# Problem with python script - invalid syntax

Tags: python

The following code that I pulled from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-68998a08e4f6) in an effort to better understand how Machine Learning and Neural Networks work, isn't working. It keeps producing an "invalid syntax" error at line 31:

```
self.weights1 += d_weights1
```

Here is the function that fails:

```
    def backprop(self):
        # application of the chain rule to find derivative of the loss function with respect to weights2 and weights1
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)))
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T, (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1))

        # update the weights with the derivative (slope) of the loss function        
        self.weights1 += d_weights1
        self.weights2 += d_weights2
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add the complete error, or at least highlight which line is line 31.

Comment: Other than that, you are missing a closing bracket in the line before. You did not copy it correctly, because it is there in the link you provided

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the future.Generating one in this case would have easily shown you the problem with your code. And please add only relvant tags and a meaningfull title. The problem is clearly a syntactic one and is not in any way related to machine-learning or neural networks.

Comment: When you get an "Invalid Syntax" error, it means that the problem comes from how you wrote the code, independently from the data behind it. Usually it means an extra or missing bracket, a missing comma, etc.

Comment: You have forgotten a brace in the line 27: d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T, (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))

Comment: Your IDE should show you which parenthesis is not closed too.

Comment: This edits is just unuserful because this code isn't complete.

Comment: If I or you would have created a minimal example this questions would not exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to put a brackets at the end of line 4

```
d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T, (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1))
```

Here is the correction:

```
d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T, (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))
```